# Movie or episode which ends with the line, "All of my tears"

Tags: identify-this-movie

Very long time ago, I guess more than 20 years, there was a series of shorter movies with a fiction and science fiction theme.

I am trying to track down a specific episode. I don't know what the running time was but I do remember some visual cues. I think it was an American production. Clothes, women's haircut, cars were 80's look. Colors were not vibrant sort of a pastel look. Not strong color contrasts.

The story was something like that. A woman, blonde, somewhere around 30, walks through the streets, across the streets and walks into a building into some kind of office, not so much different from dentist office only everything in much darker shade.

She has a sort of melancholic face expression. She takes off her blazer, sits on a chair, not quite unlike a dentist chair. Everything happens slowly, without words. And she starts to cry. As a tear runs down her cheek the doctor collects the tear and puts it in a bottle. And this scene repeats itself. She walks into an office, always somehow sad, sits down, cries and he collects her tears.

One day he gives her the bottle, big clear glass bottle, about a gallon big. She takes it, goes out and steps onto the street. In that moment we hear car brakes and tires screeching, a car veers off and almost hits her. She drops the bottle and in slow motion it breaks on the tarmac. The driver angrily shouts at her: "What was that?". She looks at him and says: "All of my tears". And for the first time she smiles. And I think those were the only two lines spoken.

I was just a kid when I saw this so my recollection might not be 100% true. But still, I would very much like to find this episode / movie.

Comment: Wow. That's a powerful image. Hope someone recognizes this soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a disappointment. I cannot believe how skewed my memory was. I was fixated on a particular search phrase form my original question. "Collecting tears" was much more fruitful.

The episode I was looking for was Season 1, Episode 16- [**The Tear Collector**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0717002/) from the [**Tales from the Darkside**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_Darkside) series.

Comment: Yeah that's happened to me quite a few times. Memory can be a treacherous bastard sometimes.